# Where is "jvisualvm" in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, java

Just upgraded to Mountain Lion (of course). I use Java on a daily basis so I asked Mac OS X to install it right away. It installed "Java 6". I am more than OK with it.

The only thing I don't have is a utility that comes (used to come at least) with it that is called 'jvisualvm'. Any ideas on how to install it on Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to download it from http://visualvm.java.net/index.html.

Comment: Just awesome...

Comment: Just DuckDuckGo (or Google)...